# Decorators, lambdas and member function calls in Python?

Tags: python, methods, decorator, self, python-decorators

What's the correct syntax?

#### Programming attempt

```
class Foo:
    def hello(self):
        print "Hello cruel world!"
 
    def greet_first(self, f):
        self.hello()
        return lambda *args, **kwargs: f(*args, **kwargs)
 
    @greet_first
    def goodbye(self, concat):
        print "Goodbye {0}".format(concat)
 
if __name__=='__main__':
    bar = Foo()
    bar.goodbye(' and thanks for all the fish')
```

#### Debug

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Foo:
  File "prog.py", line 9, in Foo
    @greet_first
TypeError: greet_first() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

#### Reference

[Click to run the code (IDEone)](http://ideone.com/ma41Ny)

Comment: rel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740626/can-a-class-method-be-a-decorator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decorator is called immediately, it is not treated as a method of `Foo` but rather is seen as a local function instead. The `@greet_first` syntax effectively means:

```
 goodbye = greet_first(goodbye)
```

and is executed *immediately*. It is *not* a bound method, so the `self` parameter is not included. There is no point in making `greet_first` a method. Move it out and remove the `self` argument altogether.

You need to adjust your decorator to return a callable to replace `goodbye`:

```
def greet_first(f):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.hello()
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

so that `self.hello()` is called every time `goodbye` is called.

If you *have* to make `greet_first` part of `Foo`, you *can* use a `@staticmethod` decorator but you have to jump through an extra hoop just to be able to use it for other method declarations; you have to treat it as the descriptor it has become and call `.__get__()` on it:

```
class Foo(object):
    def hello(self):
        print "Hello cruel world!"

    @staticmethod
    def greet_first(f):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.hello()
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @greet_first.__get__(object)
    def goodbye(self, concat):
        print "Goodbye {0}".format(concat)
```

I call `.__get__()` with an arbitrary type (`object` in this case) because `staticmethod` *ignores* that argument anyway; we can't use `Foo` here because that class has not yet been finalized while inside the code that is part of it's definition.

Note that for `@staticmethod` to work at all you need to inherit from `object` in Python 2.

Comment: Would I be looking at using a `@staticmethod` here if I wanted to keep the function attached to the object?

Comment: @AT: You cannot mix a methods (static or otherwise) with decorators. Separate the two. You *can* slap on a `@staticmethod` decorator, but it would not directly be callable as a method of it's own. You *can* then use `@Foo.greet_first` outside of the class as a decorator for other methods, yes.

Comment: @AT: That IDEOne edit is set to C++; that certainly won't work. It works in my Python 2.7 session... Switch to python and it works just fine: http://ideone.com/wa61XF

Comment: That's odd, not sure why it switched back to C++…