# Declaring decorator inside a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, wrapper, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to use custom wrappers/decorators in Python, and I'd like to declare one **inside** a class, so that I could for instance print a snapshot of the attributes. I've tried things from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11740626/5018771) with no success.

---

Here is what I'd like to do (NB: this code doesn't work, I explain what happens below)

```
class TestWrapper():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = 0

    def enter_exit_info(self, func):
        def wrapper(*arg, **kw):
            print '-- entering', func.__name__
            print '-- ', self.__dict__
            res = func(*arg, **kw)
            print '-- exiting', func.__name__
            print '-- ', self.__dict__
            return res
        return wrapper

    @enter_exit_info
    def add_in_c(self):
        self.c = self.a + self.b
        print self.c

    @enter_exit_info
    def mult_in_c(self):
        self.c = self.a * self.b
        print self.c


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = TestWrapper(2, 3)
    t.add_in_c()
    t.mult_in_c()
```

The expected output is :

```
-- entering add_in_c
-- {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 0}
5
-- exiting add_in_c
-- {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5}
-- entering mult_in_c
-- {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5}
6
-- exiting mult_in_c
-- {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 6}
```

But I this code gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cccvag\workspace\Test\src\module2.py", line 2, in <module>
    class TestWrapper():
  File "C:\Users\cccvag\workspace\Test\src\module2.py", line 18, in     TestWrapper
    @enter_exit_info
TypeError: enter_exit_info() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

And if I try `@enter_exit_info(self)` or `@self.enter_exit_info`, I get a `NameError`. What could I do?

---

**EDIT:**

I do not need above all to have the decorator *physically* declared inside the class, as long as it is able to access attributes from an instance of this class. I thought it could only be made by declaring it inside the class, [Rawing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38524581/5018771) proved me wrong.

Comment: you can use class decorator if you really want to use the class based decorator but that will be again a separate independent class.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of defining the decorator inside the class you can just intercept the `self` parameter:

```
import functools

def enter_exit_info(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *arg, **kw):
        print '-- entering', func.__name__
        print '-- ', self.__dict__
        res = func(self, *arg, **kw)
        print '-- exiting', func.__name__
        print '-- ', self.__dict__
        return res
    return wrapper

class TestWrapper():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = 0
    
    @enter_exit_info
    def add_in_c(self):
        self.c = self.a + self.b
        print self.c

    @enter_exit_info
    def mult_in_c(self):
        self.c = self.a * self.b
        print self.c


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = TestWrapper(2, 3)
    t.add_in_c()
    t.mult_in_c()
```

Comment: @wim I sure hope that's not the reason. I hardly care about the downvotes, but... I hope people realize they can just move the decorator into the class and it'll work just as well...

Comment: Yes.  The answer is fine, actually it's the same as my recommendation (see the last paragraph of my answer).

Comment: I may have been a bit unclear when I asked my question, hence the edit. This is a great solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not preserve function signature with         @functools.wraps(func)

Comment: Don't declare `self` outside of the class. It doesn't makes sense to have a 'function' (which is not a 'method' inside a class), whose first argument is 'self'. Besides, if the decorator is used over a classmethod, then the `self` parameter would have a `cls` reference. So even though your solution may work, but it is syntactically wrong. I think this is why your answer has been getting down-votes. @Aran-Fey
CC: @AdrienW

Comment: @ArchitKapoor You are right that `self` can be misleading here. The first parameter could be renamed (for example) `obj` and the code would keep the same functionality. Although I still cannot find a way to do it that generates 0 warnings, the trick proposed here does the job. Feel free to post a new Python-3 compatible answer if you know a more elegant way, as I believe myself and other people can still benefit from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

You will need to handle `self` explicitly.

```
class TestWrapper:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = 0

    def enter_exit_info(func):
        def wrapper(self, *arg, **kw):
            print '-- entering', func.__name__
            print '-- ', self.__dict__
            res = func(self, *arg, **kw)
            print '-- exiting', func.__name__
            print '-- ', self.__dict__
            return res
        return wrapper

    @enter_exit_info
    def add_in_c(self):
        self.c = self.a + self.b
        print self.c

    @enter_exit_info
    def mult_in_c(self):
        self.c = self.a * self.b
        print self.c


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = TestWrapper(2, 3)
    t.add_in_c()
    t.mult_in_c()
```

This is valid python, but it's somewhat weird to have a function at the class level which is not really a method.  Unless you have a good reason to do it this way, it would be more idiomatic to move the decorator to module level scope.

Comment: Agreed. If left in the class definition, I'd a least indicate it was private by changing its name to `_enter_exit_info`.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR : what you want is

```
def enter_exit_info(func):
    def wrapper(self, *arg, **kw):
        print '-- entering', func.__name__
        print '-- ', self.__dict__
        res = func(*arg, **kw)
        print '-- exiting', func.__name__
        print '-- ', self.__dict__
        return res
    return wrapper
```

Remember that

```
@decorate
def myfunc():
    pass
```

is really just syntactic sugar for

```
def myfunc():
    pass
my_func = decorate(my_func)
```

So since in your case, decorated functions are replaced by the decorator's `wrapper` function, it's this  `wrapper` function that will receive the current instance as first argument.

EDIT : I positively agree with other answers on the point that it makes no sense defining this decorator within the class. You don't need it to access the current instance since it's provided as the function's first argument. FWIW the `def` statement doesn't work any differently from being used within a `class` statement, it always yields a plain old `function` object. What makes the function a "method" (and 'automagically' pass the current instance as first argument) is the attribute resolution mechanism, cf https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod

Answer (score -2):

Hi do you want the output should be in dictionary format?
If you don't want the output in dictionary format u can try this....

```py
def enter_exit_info(func):
        def wrapper(*arg, **kw):
            print '-- entering', func.__name__        
            res = func(*arg, **kw)
            print '-- exiting', func.__name__
            return res
        return wrapper
```

then your output will be

```
-- entering add_in_c

5
-- exiting add_in_c

-- entering mult_in_c

6
-- exiting mult_in_c
```

Comment: Sorry dude, but this is not the point of my question. Besides, the answer is poorly edited.