# Decorator to do a test before launching each function

Tags: python, decorator

Instead of repeating `if not self.connected: ... return` for every method of this class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connected = False
    def connect(self, password):
        if password == "ab":
            self.connected = True
    def send(self, message):
        if not self.connected:
            print("abandoned because not connected")
            return
        print("sending")
    def receive(self):
        if not self.connected:
            print("abandoned because not connected")
            return
        print("receiving")
a = A()
a.send()
```

is it possible to do it with a decorator like

```
class A:

    ...

    def requires_connected(self, func):
        if self.connected:
            func()
        else:
            print("abandoned because not connected")

    @requires_connected
    def send(self, message):
        print("sending")
```

?

The latter doesn't work (`TypeError: requires_connected() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`), probably because of the arguments.

**How to make this decorator work correctly?**

Comment: Try `@self.requires_connected`

Comment: No @Raphael, it gives `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: I don't think you can use a decorator defined in the same class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Declaring decorator inside a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524332/declaring-decorator-inside-a-class/38524704#38524704), I finally found the solution:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connected = False

    def requires_connected(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.connected:
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                print("abandoned because not connected")
        return wrapper

    @requires_connected
    def send(self, message):
        print(f"sending '{message}'")

    # this is syntactic sugar for:
    #    def send(self, message):
    #       ...
    #    send = requires_connected(send)

a = A()
a.send("hello")
a.connected = True
a.send("hello")
```

Comment: I recommend to flag the decorators inside the same class as either `classmethod` or `staticmethod` if possible (in this case a static one)

Comment: Ok @cards, can you remind me the benefit of doing this? I never remember this ;)

Comment: Just for a better organization of the class... if you have a class with many methods, distinguish those who decorates among those who perform the actions could  be useful for maintain the code [`classmethod` needs a `cls` parameter as a reference of the class, `static` not; Notice further that your `requires_connected` (undecorated) will change type depending if called from a instance or from a class]

Answer (score 1):

The following refactor should solve the problem

```
# decorator as global function
def requires_connected(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.connected:
            func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print("abandoned because not connected")
        return func
    return wrapper


class A:
    ...
    @requires_connected
    def send(self, message):
        print("sending")
```

Comment: I will have a look, sure:) But my original answer was correct, right? Bit confused with the edit**s**

Comment: Not it is not correct when used in the main code.

Comment: Some misunderstanding I will fix it

Comment: No it doesn"t work because, in your last code, send isn't a method of the class `A` anymore ;)

Comment: You are right, the indentation confused me a bit

Comment: Never mind @cards, thanks anyway. My posted solution (other answer) now works.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked how I did this a while ago.

I simply left out the self argument in the decorator definition, I don't know if this is good practice though:

```py
import functools
class MyClass:
    def error_inside_context(func):
        """ Function wrapper to ensure function is not executed inside any context."""
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if args[0]._context_depth != 0:
                raise RuntimeError('Cannot use this Funtion inside context')
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @error_inside_context
    def query(self, msg):
         ...
```

`args[0]` is then the self passed to the wrapped function.